# R matching letters and numbers with a For Loop

Tags: r, loops, matrix, letter, ordinal

I am trying to print a matching letter and number on every line. However, the code repeats itself 26 x 26 times instead of 26 x 1 time. I hoped the break after reaching the first "z" would stop the loop but it doesn't.

```
for (i in 1:26) {
  l = letters
  num = sapply(1:26, toOrdinal)
  print(paste0(l," is the ",num," letter of the alphabet."))
  if (l == "z") {
    break
  }
}
```

I wrote an alternate piece of code that puts the data in a matrix to control the print, but I would like to make the top piece work for my own edification.

```
#Create Data Matrix contain desired data to restrict continuous printing
matrix.letters <- matrix(nrow = 26, ncol = 3, dimnames = list(NULL, c("num", "letter", "ordinal")))
matrix.letters[,'num'] <- 1:26
matrix.letters[, 'ordinal'] <- sapply(1:26, toOrdinal)
matrix.letters[,'letter'] <- letters

#create index observation
letters.df <- as.data.frame(matrix.letters)

#YES - correct print achieved
for (i in nrow(letters.df)) {
  print(paste0(letters.df$letter," is the ",letters.df$ordinal, " letter of the alphabet."))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, please be clear about non-base packages. I'm inferring the `toOrdinal::toOrdinal function in your question.

Up front, your issue is that you are looping, but you should be *indexing* using that loop count within multiple places in your code:

```r
for (i in 1:26) {
  l = letters[i]
  num = toOrdinal(i)
  print(paste0(l," is the ",num," letter of the alphabet."))
  if (l == "z") {
    break
  }
}
# [1] "a is the 1st letter of the alphabet."
# [1] "b is the 2nd letter of the alphabet."
# [1] "c is the 3rd letter of the alphabet."
# [1] "d is the 4th letter of the alphabet."
# [1] "e is the 5th letter of the alphabet."
# [1] "f is the 6th letter of the alphabet."
# [1] "g is the 7th letter of the alphabet."
# [1] "h is the 8th letter of the alphabet."
# [1] "i is the 9th letter of the alphabet."
# [1] "j is the 10th letter of the alphabet."
# [1] "k is the 11th letter of the alphabet."
# [1] "l is the 12th letter of the alphabet."
# [1] "m is the 13th letter of the alphabet."
# [1] "n is the 14th letter of the alphabet."
# [1] "o is the 15th letter of the alphabet."
# [1] "p is the 16th letter of the alphabet."
# [1] "q is the 17th letter of the alphabet."
# [1] "r is the 18th letter of the alphabet."
# [1] "s is the 19th letter of the alphabet."
# [1] "t is the 20th letter of the alphabet."
# [1] "u is the 21st letter of the alphabet."
# [1] "v is the 22nd letter of the alphabet."
# [1] "w is the 23rd letter of the alphabet."
# [1] "x is the 24th letter of the alphabet."
# [1] "y is the 25th letter of the alphabet."
# [1] "z is the 26th letter of the alphabet."
```

As @Joe said in the comment, in your original code, `paste0` is getting `l` (length 26) and `num` (length 26), and therefore it is returning a vector (length 26) that is being printed. My first thought on your `for` loop was inefficient reassignments, since `l = letters` was doing exactly the same thing each pass, same with `num = sapply(..)`, so those could have been moved outside the loop. In fact, that can happen, with slightly different code:

```r
Ls <- letters
nums <- sapply(1:26, toOrdinal)
for (i in 1:26) {
  print(paste0(Ls[i]," is the ",nums[i]," letter of the alphabet."))
  if (Ls[i] == "z") {
    break
  }
}
```

And one last bit of "unnecessary" code there: `break` is useful when you expect that the `for` (or `while` or `repeat` or ...) code will go on too long. In this case, we know that `Ls[i] == "z"` happens on the 26th time in the loop, and it will be stopping on its own accord regardless. So for this loop, the `break` portion is unnecessary. (If this is just an exercise for flow-control, then it's a good lesson to know.)

Comment: Indexing! I can not believe I overlooked that. For whatever reason, in all my different attempts I never once indexed. I was trying different ways in tricking the counter/loop. Thanks, guys for both examples. I guess I had a case of counter tunnel vision.